# В Webview не работает transform

Tags: avalonia

Хочу сделать как во времена IE такое
`<a style="border-radius: 0px; border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); border-image: none; transform: rotate(-90deg); resize: vertical horizontal;">&nbsp;хочу вертикально&nbsp;</a>`
и облом, div вертится а анкор нет, а надо именно анкор . Как обойти ? ну или как сделать чтобы div не переводил строку ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понял вопрос про WebView, но не переводить строку это `display: inline`, если вы о позиционировании `div`.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Arthur Conan Doyle , спасибо за div но при display: inline перестает работать transform .

Comment: Проблему решил display: inline-block , и якорь завертелся и div стал строчным , спасибо Arthur Conan Doyle за наводку .